# Is asking suggestions on topic on EE stack exchange acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Is asking suggestions on EE stack exchange on topic?

For example:

1. I'm looking for a intro semiconductor textbook, what are titles of books that have helped you?
2. My circuit design for this problem looks like this, is there any suggestions for me to improve?
3. I'm looking for a beginner microcontroller, what are MCUs you have worked with that had documentation, guides and are generally user friendly?

I'm just trying to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Not a good fit for the main Q&A board.  Questions like this routinely get closed as opinion-based.
   Should be alright for our [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).
2. Could work on the main Q&A board, provided that everything else is good with the question.
3. Polls "suggest me a uC" routinely get closed.  This kind of information becomes outdated quickly.  It's also <strike>religion-</strike>  opinion-based.

Comment: I never knew there was a EE chat. Thanks for pointing that out!